# Lost privileges on Profiles

Tags: profile

I have set for 3 times the Manage public templates on a given profile, but every other day this flags got reset.

What could be the reason for this to happen? Someone pushing profiles from a Sandbox would be the only possibility?

Comment: Check the setup audit trail to see who is overriding it.  If you have developers doing deploys via API they might not realize you're doing it in production and a continuous integration environment (also related to developers) might be overwriting it on deploy.

Setup Audit Trail:
https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_monitorsetup.htm

Comment: I have verified that myself has enabled this three times, but in the downloaded CSV there is no sign of it going back to "disabled"